# Mongo: Why execution time is quick but response is slow

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a very heavy collection, ~ 2 billion records.

[image]

When I tried query to this collection with limit 20K records, the response time is very slow, about 40s.

But when I explain the query on Studio3T, it's response very quick and time report like above image is 61ms for total scan/examine time.

```
totalKeysExmained = 20000
totalDocsExmained = 20000
nReturned = 20000
```

So why response is slow ?

Comment: If you're downloading all 20k records in one go, that may well take some time…?

Comment: @deceze does it mean the query, index is not matter? the root cause is response is heavy ? I also think about it because I saw size of documents fetch from regular collection is 10Mib. but I'm not sure, so need to more confirming

Comment: In browser F12 or such and check the network traffic. Try storing the results first at the server, to separate problems, mongodb, network traffic and things like compression.

Comment: @JoopEggen I'm using studio3t, just open monitor app on macos. Recieved data is > 10Mb